# Can I find the next prime with sufficient small residue efficiently?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

Suppose, positive integers $N,a,b$ are given.

The object is to determine the smallest prime $p$ larger than $a$ such that $N$ modulo $p$ is smaller than $b$.

> Can I determine $p$ efficiently (without just checking all primes until the desired prime is found) ?

Example

$$N=40!$$

$$a=9\cdot 10^{15}$$

$$b=10^{10}$$

Brute force gives the result :

```
? n=40!;a=9*10^15;a=nextprime(a+1);while(n%a>=10^10,a=nextprime(a+1));p=a;print(
p)
9000000017042521
?
```

Is there a way to speed up the search considerably ?

Comment: *"The object is to determine the smallest prime p larger than a such that N modulo a is smaller than b."* I think there is a typo here. Where does $p$ fit in?

Comment: @Mike You are right, fixed.

Comment: I have a hunch chebyshev function can help with this, especially as numbers get larger, but it is nothing more than a hunch.

Comment: This is just a question: What about the easier problem of finding an *integer* (prime or no)  $q>a$ s.t. $N$ modulo $q$ is less than $b$